# Java WS : Where is the XSD part?

Tags: java, web-services

I started learning Java Web Services following the book "Java Web Services : Up and Running".
In some sections of the book, the author talks about some `xsd` parts.
The problem is that when I try the code and when I generate the `WSDL`, I don't get those parts.

Here is an example of a WS implementation :

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "SkiImageService")
// @HandlerChain(file = "../handlers/handler-chain.xml")
public class SkiImageService {
  private static final String[] names = {"nordic.jpg", "tele.jpg", "alpine.jpg"};
  private String default_key;
  private Map<String, String> photos;

  public SkiImageService() {
    photos = new HashMap<String, String>();
    photos.put("nordic", "nordic.jpg");
    photos.put("alpine", "alpine.jpg");
    photos.put("telemk", "telemk.jpg");
    default_key = "nordic";
  }

  // Create a named image from the raw bytes.
  private Image createImage(String name) {
    byte[] bytes = getRawBytes(name);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    Iterator iterators = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpeg");
    ImageReader iterator = (ImageReader) iterators.next();
    try {
      ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
      iterator.setInput(iis, true);
      return iterator.read(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Create a list of all available images.
  private List<Image> createImageList() {
    List<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();
    Set<String> key_set = photos.keySet();
    for (String key : key_set) {
      Image image = createImage(key);
      if (image != null) {
        list.add(image);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  // Returns one image given the image's name.
  @WebMethod
  public Image getImage(String name) {
    return createImage(name);
  }

  // Returns a list of all available images.
  @WebMethod
  public List<Image> getImages() {
    return createImageList();
  }

  // Read the bytes from the file for one image.
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private byte[] getRawBytes(String name) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
      String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
      String base_name = cwd + sep + "jpegs" + sep;
      String file_name = base_name + name + ".jpg";
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_name);

      // Send default image if there's none with this name.
      if (in == null) {
        in = new FileInputStream(base_name + "nordic.jpg");
      }
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      int n = 0;
      while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n); // append to ByteArrayOutputStream
      }
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
  }

}
```

When I look to my WSDL, I don't find the following :

```
<xs:complexType name="getImagesResponse"> 
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="getImageResponse"> 
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"></xs:element> </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where can I find the XSD file/part ?

Regards,

Mick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at the types section of the WSDL (near the top). For example, here's that section from a WSDL for a project I'm working on:

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/FloeClient/localFiles?xsd=1" namespace="http://app.client.floe.iceberg.com/"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Note the xsd reference. If I were to open that URL, I'd see the XSD. Look for an xsd:import statements in your WSDL.

Most WSDL generators will include an XSD. But it doesn't have to. It's perfectly valid for all of the types to be defined in the WSDL. So if you don't have a reference to an XSD, it's not an error.

Comment: Thank you so much. That what I wanted to know.